# Difference in usage and implementation of ManualResetEvent(Slim), Semaphore(Slim) and ReaderWriterLock(Slim)

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0

With .net 4.0 several new classes have been added relating to threading: [ManualResetEventSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.aspx), [SemaphoreSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx) and [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).

What is the difference between the Slim versions and the older classes, and when should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`ReaderWriterLockSlim` is a better version of `ReaderWriterLock` that is faster and  doesn't suffer from writer starvation

`ManualResetEventSlim` and `SemaphoreSlim` are fully managed versions of a `ManualResetEvent` and `Semaphore` that spin-wait for a while before falling back to kernel objects, and so are faster than the old versions when wait times are short.

Comment: +1: Yeah, my own personal tests indicate that the RWL was up to 15x slower than a plain old `lock`. The newer RWLS improved this quite a bit, but it can still be up to 5x slower. Of course, everyone's mileage will vary.

Comment: It will certainly be slower than a Monitor (lock) for general purpose thread safety where write contention is a major problem. But for read contention heavy systems ReaderWriterLockSlim will outperform a Monitor by a potentially high degree. Different locking primitives target different scenarios

Comment: I just did some more *accurate* testing. It looks like RWL is ~5x slower than a `lock` and RWLS is about 2x slower. So RWLS does improve things quite a bit. And yes, reader-writer locks certainly have advantages over plain old locks :)

Comment: So i should always use the slim versions?

Comment: In the case of ReaderWriterLock yes. In the case of ManualResetEvent and Semaphore, yes unless you want to coordinate across the AppDomain or Process boundary - in that case you'll need the older versions as you'll need kernel object support

Comment: Note that ManualResetEventSlim and SemaphoreSlim **will** create the kernel objects if the waiting takes long enough.

Comment: the waiting time is very important in use of slim version or not.if waiting time is long, you should use older (fat) version.

Answer (score 29):

I've made some **illustrations** to help me visualize the the sync primitives. Hope it helps someone else too.

## SemaphoreSlim

[image]

## CountdownEvent

[image]

## Barrier

[image]

## ManualResetEventSlim

[image]

Answer (score 8):

To quote directly from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbefs30.aspx)

"In the .NET Framework version 4, you can use the System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim class for better performance when wait times are expected to be very short, and when the event does not cross a process boundary"

Answer (score 7):

`ManualResetEventSlim` and `SemaphoreSlim` are lighter versions of their kernel counterparts and don't allocate any kernel objects unless their `WaitHandle` property is called.

These types do not block directly when Wait is called, instead they spin briefly before blocking in case it got a signal

`ManualResetEventSlim` constructor can take `SpinCount` to customize the number of spns before blocking

Both these types support cancellation where you can pass a CancellationToken to the Wait method

`SemaphoreSlim` exposes a `CurrentCount` property where the `Semaphore` doesn't

`ManualResetEventSlim` has an `IsSet` property where `ManualResetEvent` doesn't.